# Why are "misplaced" modifiers incorrect in some cases and correct in others?

Tags: modifiers, participial-phrases

In some cases, phrases don't have to be next to what they're modifying and in some cases they do.

For example, "enraged by the ruling" is not considered a misplaced modifier here.

> James launched into a frenzied argument, enraged by the ruling.

But it would be awkward to write something like

> In 1989, he came up with his idea for a line of Southern-inspired cuisine, a time when there were no convenience foods.

I know what the ordering should be in the second sentence, but help me understand the rules behind these cases.

Comment: Suppose _enraged by the ruling_ started with _because he was_ -- which wouldn't change the meaning. Note that that clause will still do fine at the end, but is awkward following _James_. That's because it doesn't nececesarily modify _James_, but more likely the entire main clause, as a purpose participle. Oh, and BTW, I have no idea what you mean by "misplaced modifiers".

Comment: Note that your second sentence is not **awkward**, it is simply meaningless, wrong.

Comment: Well the second sentence should be: "He came up with his idea for a line of Southern-inspired cuisine in 1989, a time when there were no convenience foods." It's not meaningless - just ordered incorrectly.

Comment: I can't find the modifiers or what things are supposedly modified, in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

It depends mainly on the meaning of the whole sentence to consider any modifier "misplaced". This means that if the sentence has only one clear interpretation or it can't be misunderstood by the reader or the listener, the modifier causes no problem wherever it is placed.However, if the sentence bears more than one interpretation and leaves the reader puzzled to figure out the speaker's intention, the modifier, in this case, is regarded as "misplaced".
For example, "with an umbrella" is a misplaced modifier in the following sentence:

> "The old woman hit the man with an umbrella."

Who had the umbrella? The man or the old woman? Did the old woman use an umbrella to hit the man, or the man was carrying an umbrella when he was hit by the old woman? No one knows but the speaker!

Now let's consider the modifier "given longer time to answer the questions" in the following sentence:

> "Given longer time to answer the questions, the students looked pleased."

The modifier is not "misplaced" since there is only one meaning captured by any reader or listener regardless the position of the modifier.

> "Given longer time to answer the questions, the students looked pleased."
>
> "The students looked pleased given longer time to answer the questions."
>
> "The students, given longer time to answer the questions, looked pleased."

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware, your second sentence is incorrectly ordered. It should be:

> In 1989, a time when there were no convenience foods, he came up with his idea for a line of Southern-inspired cuisine.

By ordering it the way you have done, you are claiming that *"a time when there were no convenience foods"* is a modifier on *"he"*, when in fact you meant it to be a modifier on *"1989"*. An adjective-clause modifier should be adjacent to the clause containing the subject it is modifying.

Your first example is not ambiguous to the reader because the modifier is applied to the subject (and not the object) in the adjacent clause:

> James launched into a frenzied argument, enraged by the ruling.

In order to make *frenzied argument* the subject of the clause, you would need to rewrite it to be:

> A frenzied argument was launched into by James, enraged by the ruling.

This makes *"enraged by the ruling"* a dangling modifier because you intend it to be applied to *James*, but *James* is the object of the clause, not the subject.

Comment: Then by the same logic, wouldn't my first sentence be incorrectly ordered? Why is it that "enraged by the ruling" does NOT have be placed next to "James"?

Comment: I thought modifiers modify a noun, not another clause. In thise case, "James."

Comment: That logic still does not hold for the classic dangling modifier examples such as: "Jumping from flower to flower, the boy watched the bee." In this case, "jumping to flower to flower" is adjacent to the clause that contains the noun that it's modifying, but the sentence is incorrect.

Comment: @user1411569: as Ian MacDonald has explained, the modifier is considered to be incorrect when it modifies the object of a clause, and correct when it modifies the subject. That rule fits perfectly with that "classic dangling modifier example". It doesnt matter which noun is physically closer in the sentence. Do you understand what the difference is between a subject and object?

Answer (score -3):

It's very simple.  if you **remove the modifier** the remaining sentence should be correct:

James launched into a frenzied argument.   Correct.

In 1989 a time when there were no convenience foods.  Meaningless.

Comment: "a time when there were no convenience foods" IS the modifier.